# how to show and update data from database instantly after insertion of data in database in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recorder app.It records sound in a fragment. I want to show recorded item in another fragment in a recyclerview. Now what happens is recorder is working fine. I have seen that data are inserted in database. But recorded items are not displayed in recyclerview. I want to show recoeded items on recyclerview as soon as data insertion.

Here is my adapter class---

```
    public class FileViewerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FileViewerAdapter.RecordingViewHolder> implements OnDatabaseChangedListener
    {
        Context mContext;
        DBHelper mDatabase;
        RecordingItem item;
        LinearLayoutManager llm;
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "FileViewerAdapter";

        @Override
        public FileViewerAdapter.RecordingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
            mContext=parent.getContext();
            return new RecordingViewHolder(v);
        }

        public FileViewerAdapter(Context context, LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
            mDatabase = new DBHelper(mContext);
            mDatabase.setOnDatabaseChangedListener(this);
            llm = linearLayoutManager;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final FileViewerAdapter.RecordingViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            item=getItem(position);
            int itemDuration=item.getLength();

            int minute= (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(itemDuration);
            int second= (int) ( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(itemDuration)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minute));

            holder.vName.setText(item.getName());
            holder.vLength.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minute, second));
            holder.vDateAdded.setText(
                    DateUtils.formatDateTime(
                            mContext,
                            item.getTime(),
                            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));

            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        PlaybackFragment playbackFragment =
                                new PlaybackFragment().newInstance(getItem(holder.getPosition()));

                        FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) mContext)
                                .getSupportFragmentManager();

                        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                        playbackFragment.show(fm,"dialog playback");
                        ft.commit();

                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"exception",e);
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>() ;
                    arrayList.add(mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_file_share));
                    arrayList.add(mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_file_rename));
                    arrayList.add(mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_file_delete));

                    final CharSequence[] items= arrayList.toArray(new CharSequence[arrayList.size()]);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                    builder.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_title_options));
                    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                            if(position==0)
                            {
                                shareFileDialog(holder.getPosition());
                            }

                            if(position==1)
                            {
                                renameFileDialog(holder.getPosition());
                            }

                            if(position==2)
                            {
                                deleteFileDialog(holder.getPosition());
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.setNegativeButton(mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_action_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDatabase.getCount();
        }
}
```

Here is the 'OnCreateView' method of the fragment class where the recyclerview will be shown----

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_file_viewer, container, false);

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //newest to oldest order (database stores from oldest to newest)
    llm.setReverseLayout(true);
    llm.setStackFromEnd(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mFileViewerAdapter = new FileViewerAdapter(getActivity(), llm);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFileViewerAdapter);
    mFileViewerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return v;
}
```

So, what is the problem? Please someone help!!!

Comment: Once you insert your record to your database, refresh your adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` once the data is inserted into database.

Comment: mFileViewerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); use it after inserted to database

Comment: Still the same problem.Here is what I have done:--- SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();cv.put(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_NAME, recordingName);
        mFileViewerAdapter=new FileViewerAdapter(mContext);
        mFileViewerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: To get automatic updates you need to manually reload the data or use something like a cursorloader (don't recommend) SqlBrite also provides this functionality and I would recommend looking into SqlBrite.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your i have understood that, you have not implemented the recyclerview Adapter properly.

Select the Data from DB and store it in Arraylist and pass it to the Adapter, and access the data from it and set it to the VIews.

After inserting the data to Database(i hope SQLite) you have to fetch the data again and add it to Arraylist and update the Recyclerview by calling the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); from the Activity/Fragment.

By this way you implement the clean and maintainable code.

Comment: Still no result.Here is what I have done---in oncreateview method of fragment -----mFileViewerAdapter.swapArray(); In fragment------- public void swapArray()
    {
        getResults();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }